# Is every non-solvable group a product of a set and a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Every solvable group is a Zappa-Szep-product. Non-solvable groups need not be a Zappa-Szep-product, $A_6$ being the smallest counter-example.

However, if we define $$S:={(),(236),(456),(246),(263),(162)}$$ and $$H:=<(12345),(345)>$$

we have $H=A_5$ and $SH=A_6$ (but $HS\ne A_6$ because $(465)$ is not in $HS$). $S$ is not a subgroup, therefore $H$ and $S$ do not commute.

Note that the product of two permutations is done from left to right, as it is in GAP, so the first permutation acts first.

> Is every finite group with a composite order (in particular a non-solvable group) a product of this kind ? If yes, how can I prove it ?

Comment: If $G$ has a subgroup $H$, and $S$ is a complete set of left coset representatives, then $G=SH$. This can, of course, always be done for a group of composite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $G$ is a group of composite order $n$, choose a proper subgroup $H$ and let $S$ be a complete set of left coset representatives. Then, $G=SH$.

(Note that such a subgroup can always be found. For example, $H=\langle g\rangle$ for some nontrivial element $g\in G$. If $G$ happens to be cyclically generated by $g$, then we can take $H=\langle g^d\rangle$ for some divisor $d$ of $n$.)